# Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Tags: phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send the smtp emails. If I use the same setting in a WordPress site, it works fine. But my priority is to use in a custom php page. And there, it is giving the following errors

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

My Code is here below

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'emails/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 587;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "mzubim@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('mzubim@gmail.com', 'Zubair Mushtaq');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@gmail.com', 'Secure Developer');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('abulogics@gmail.com', 'Abulogicss');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML("convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body");
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: I gather you didn't read the error message or the docs it points to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this its working fine

```
<?php
    include "emails/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"; 

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "";
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('mzubim@gmail.com', 'Zubair Mushtaq');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('replyto@gmail.com', 'Secure Developer');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('abulogics@gmail.com', 'Abulogicss');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML("convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body");
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thakns Ashu. It will solve my problem. But using your email and password is not the solution of my problem. I just want to enable my gmail account to work with smtp. Thanks again.

Comment: I also did this. The proble was with the goDaddy hosting. They wasted my two days for debugging this. Anyway thanks for your great help.

Comment: no issues #zubairbhai,  so finally you got answer ryt?

Comment: Yes dear. goDaddy created a workspace for email and they instructed me to use their smtp instead of Gmail. Now, there is no email delay. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider increasing the debugging whilst you have the problem:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL ;
```

(see [PHPMailer Debug messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020031/phpmailer-debug-messages))

My issue finally turned out to be the ports on my mail requesting server were not open to even get to the mail server (i.e. fix the firewall).

Answer (score 0):

the PHPMailer docs says that if it

->  //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

And in your case u used ssl.