# PHPMailer Debug messages

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer and I would like to save in my DB some debug info.

The code below shows how to save debug info when using an SMTP server like below:

```
mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant
$mail->isSMTP();  // tell the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                  // set the SMTP port
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourhost.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "name@yourhost.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "your password";     // SMTP account password
```

According to the PHPMailer documentation SMTPDebug has 4 levels.

```
SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0): Disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default).
SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT (1): Output messages sent by the client.
SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER (2): as 1, plus responses received from the server (this is the most useful setting).
SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION (3): as 2, plus more information about the initial connection - this level can help diagnose STARTTLS failures.
SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4): as 3, plus even lower-level information, very verbose, don't use for debugging SMTP, only low-level problems.
```

When I use level 2 I get Client and Server responses logged to the screen.

Is there a way to have only Server responses logged? I do not want to save Clients request too as it may have some sensitive data (The email content sent itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can inject a closure that captures the debug output and writes it to your DB. There is [an example in the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_Debugoutput):

It might be something like this (including filtering out client messages):

```
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) use ($db) {
    if (strpos($str, 'CLIENT -> SERVER') === false) {
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO maildebug SET level = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $level)."', message = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $str)."'");
    }
};
```

A somewhat tidier option would be to accumulate all the debug output in a temporary variable, and only write it to the DB if there is a problem.

Comment: Did you misunderstood my question? I know how to save the debug output to a DB, what I want is to save only the server response. Right now with SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = 1 displays client request and SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = 2 it displays both client and server response. Is there a way to get only server response in debug output?

Comment: I thought you were having trouble with preventing output, not which messages were logged. There is no built-in option for this (debug level is not a bitfield), however, client->server messages have an easily identifiable prefix which you can filter on - adding to my answer.

Comment: Could you clarify this please?