# my Code not sending email from my website

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

kindly help out on this where am I going Wrong

I have a website with a contact form the problem is when one send email from my website it show a success message but the message is not recieved on the other side.

this is is my code

```
   <?php
  require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php'; 
  // creates object
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
  if(isset($_POST['btn_send']))
  {
   $email      = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
   $subject    = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
   $text_message    = "Hello";      
   $message  = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
 try
   {
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
    $mail->Port        = '465';             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username   ="myemail@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password   ="myemailpassword";            
    $mail->SetFrom('myemail@gmail.com','STAMP');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("myemail@gmail.com","STAMP");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody    = $message;

    if($mail->Send())
    {

     $msg = "Hi, Your mail successfully sent to".$email." ";

    }
   }
   catch(phpmailerException $ex)
   {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>".$ex->errorMessage()."</div>";
   }
  } 


?> 



<form  method="post" action="">

<div class="form-group input-row">
  <label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"for="first_name">Email</label>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <input    class = "form-control" type="email" name="email">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group input-row">
  <label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"for="last_name">Subject</label>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group input-row">
  <label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"for="first_name">Message</label>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
<label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"for="first_name"></label>
  <input type="submit" name="btn_send" class = "btn btn-primary" value="Send Message">  
</div>
</form>
```

Am expecting when the sender sends a Message it is sent successifully and the recepient recieves the message

Comment: Use $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; that will help you to understand what is the error because it can we from email side also not only from code. If you are using Google email you need to open low secure app in Google account.

Comment: AM getting this SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Comment: Using which email service provider/ xampp?

Comment: Here is your answer you will find check it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061041/failed-to-connect-to-server-connection-refused-111

Comment: That isnt working for me

Comment: try $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; and read the error carefully